# Could not find the 'Customer_Interactions' feed filter on the Case layout. Ensure that your org is not using Record Types for Cases

Tags: trailhead

I am working on the [Using Feed Filters to Manage Your Feed](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/service_casefeed_basics/units/service_casefeed_basics_filters) module on Trailhead and facing the below issue. How do I add feed filter to custom layout?

[image: Create a Feed filter and Add it to the Page Layout]

I created this filter:

[image: Feed Filter Detail]

Comment: Well, it says you need to create the filter and add it to the layout. You demonstrated the former...did you do the latter? Have you actually added the filter to the layout?

Comment: I would suspect that the instructions to add it to the layout (your question) is within the text of the trailhead module. Did you read the module at all? In the off chance that they forgot to add the core instructions in the module here is the help and training that can easily be found with a quick google search: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=case_interaction_feed_filters.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: @Eric - Yes I read whole module, but I dont know how we can add that. I will again go through this module and lets see if I get any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to follow below. Done ! This works

**Adding Filters to the Case Layout Page**
To add a standard feed filter to your case layout page:

- From Setup, enter Cases in the Quick Find box, then select Page Layouts.
- Click Edit next to the case page layout that you want to add feed filters to.
- Click Feed View. (Hint: It’s in the top right menu.)

[image]

- Scroll down to Feed Filter Options. Where it says Select Filters, you’ll see two lists: Available and Selected.
- Select a feed filter from the Available list and use the right arrow to move it to the Selected list. You can change the order of filters using the up and down arrows.

[image]

- Save

Comment: If someone is still not able to verify the challenge even after following these steps try creating a new trailhead playground and follow the steps as that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this same issue. There was no record Type. 
But I,ve got 4 Cases Pages Layouts and 3 custom Profiles.  The affected pages were not the same according to the profiles.
I modified the **Page Layout Assignment** of the Case object so that every profile has the same (called "**Case Layout**"). I've modified the Feed View of  "Case Layout" and finally the challenge was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, like Amit Jain had to create a new trailhead playground for use on only this trailhead.  I was using a playground for the Case Feed module and wasn't able to pass this trailhead in that playground.

I launched a totally new playground and only made the Case Feed Filters for Customer_Interactions using the Case Comment Feed set for All Users, applied it to the Case Page Layout, and set the Page Layout Assignment for all profiles to this layout.

Only once I did this in a totally new playground did this work, finally!!